# Entity Framework: Set max count for child entities

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a parent with a list of entites. It is very important that the child entities do not exceed XX records. The count of max childs is specified in the parent.

Right now I check this by custom code, but due to external API requests, records could have time to be added between the check and the database insert.
Is it possible to prevent inserts in Entity Framework to solve my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: you solve zhis only by having a unique constraint, which would not allow duplicates

Comment: I don't believe this is supported as part of EF (or SQLServer). It could be implemented with triggers on the DB side (but you have to be extremely careful with triggers, generally).

Answer (score 0):

not quite following you are receiving a Parent entity with an IEnumerable of children correct?

can't you just save off the children,  set the children to  null,  add back in the children with the limit and save the changes?

something like

```
var myParent = Parent;
    var limit = Parent.MaxChildren;
    myparent.Children = null;
    myParent.Children = Parent.Children.take(limit);
    db.Parent.add(myParent)
    db.SaveChanges();
```